# Excel: Nesting AND and COUNTIF in an IF

Tags: excel, if-statement, countif

I'm struggling to count cell based upon criteria. I can make each formula work by itself but trying to nest them together turns it into scrambled eggs. What am I doing wrong?

```
=IF(
AND(
ATTENDANCE!$A:$A=C5,
ATTENDANCE!$B:$B=D5,
ATTENDANCE!$2:$2>=V2,
ATTENDANCE!$2:$2<AD2),
COUNTIF(ATTENDANCE!4:4,ATTENDANCE!$AA$3)+
COUNTIF(ATTENDANCE!4:4,ATTENDANCE!$AC$3)+
COUNTIF(ATTENDANCE!4:4,ATTENDANCE!$BG$3)+
COUNTIF(ATTENDANCE!4:4,ATTENDANCE!$BY$3),
"error")
```

- ATTENDANCE!$A:$A contains a list of last names and C5 is the name I'm
  looking for.
- ATTENDANCE!$B:$B contains a list of first names and D5 is the name
  I'm looking for.
- ATTENDANCE!$2:$2 contains weekly dates and V2 and AD2 are specific
  dates. Between V2 and AD2 are a range of dates.
- ATTENDANCE!4:4 contains certain characters that I want to tally.
- $AA$3, $AC$3, $BG$3 and $BY$3 reference the characters I'm wanting to
  count.

I'll try to upload an example when  I can (working in a school and lessons start soon).

Thanx for looking,
Sam

Comment: Why not just do the test of col A =C5 in the countifs() ?

Comment: Show your data and desired output with your attempt.